# MongoError: can't convert from BSON type string to Date

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am using node js API that selects a date from mongoDb. I have a field in mongodb which stores datetime value

```
{
 conDate : "2020-12-09 00:00:00"
}
```

I want to convert this to 12/09/2020 (m/d/Y format). I have tried the following code

```
this.gameModel.aggregate(
    [
      {
        $project: {
           monthDayYear: { $dateToString: { format: "%m/%d/%Y", date: "$conDate" } },
           
        }
      }
    ]
 )
```

But this results in following error

> MongoError: can't convert from BSON type string to Date

How can I convert the datetime to required format in node js.

Answer (score -2):

You should **never** store date/time values as strings, use proper `Date` object.

Convert the string to `Date`, then you can extract

```
monthDayYear: { $dateToString: { format: "%m/%d/%Y", 
   date: { $dateFromString: { dateString: "$conDate", format: "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"} } } 
},
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/92OvwEmt3rY)